# URL no encontrada, ASP.NET MVC - Metodo [HttpPost]

Tags: c#, asp.net, http

Estoy aprendiendo mvc con .net y tengo el siguiente problema: al intentar hacer envio mediante [httpPost], me dice "URL no encontrada". Vi varios tutoriales y lo hago de mismo manera de como los explican y me sigue saliendo el error.

-- Este sería el método de la carpeta HomeControlerr que retorna  la vista Contact.cshtml.

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Contact(string Nombre)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Mi nombre es : " + Nombre;

            return View();
        }
```

Y este el código de Contact.csHtml .

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Contact";
}
<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>
<h3>@ViewBag.Message</h3>

<div>

    <form  action =" /Home/Contact "  method="post">

        <input type="text" name="Nombre" placeholder="Ingrese" />
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />


    </form>


</div>
```

En atributo action de la etiqueta Form tambien intente poner la ruta : "~/Views/Home/Contact.cshtml" pero de igual manera no funciona. Desde ya muchas gracias...

Answer (score 0):

Quizás deberías usar la directiva Html.BeginForm en vez de la etiqueta `<form></form>`

Por ejemplo:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Contact";
}
<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>
<h3>@ViewBag.Message</h3>

<div>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Contact ", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
  <input type="text" name="Nombre" placeholder="Ingrese" />
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />


   }


</div>
```